# Is it possible to indent wrapped lines in a multicol layout?

Tags: book-design, poetry

I'm trying to print song lyrics in a two-column layout. Some lines of lyrics are longer than a column width and in those cases I'd like to wrap the indented line like so:

[image: Sample output]

I used `\indent` to accomplish this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\\
Consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
Fusce justo massa, facilisis maximus \indent metus non\\
Et magna nec, porta interdum justo.\\
```

Is there a way to have this happen automatically so I don't have to add the `\indent` manually for every long line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way with a list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,showframe}
\begin{document}
  \begin{description}[nosep,leftmargin=\parindent,labelsep=0pt]
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  \item Consectetur adipiscing elit.
  \item Fusce justo massa, facilisis maximus facilisis maximus facilisis maximus facilisis maximus metus non
  \item Et magna nec, porta interdum justo.
  \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Change `\parindent` in `leftmargin=\parindent` as you wish to push the second (onwards) lines to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Even simpler with the `verse` environment from the same package.

Define a new environment `myverse`

```
\newenvironment{myverse}
 {\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}%
  \setlength{\vindent}{\parindent}%
  \begin{verse}}
 {\end{verse}}
```

and use it like in the following example

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{verse}
\newenvironment{myverse}
 {\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}%
  \setlength{\vindent}{\parindent}%
  \begin{verse}}
 {\end{verse}}

\begin{document}

\begin{myverse}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\\
  Consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
  Fusce justo massa, facilisis maximus facilisis maximus facilisis maximus facilisis maximus metus non\\
  Et magna nec, porta interdum justo.\\
\end{myverse}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

With this solution you can also preserve your document structure.